# ror 400/Bad Request when switching from axios.request() to axios.post() for PayPal API. Config file setup remains the same

Tags: react-native, axios

question is pretty simple, i'm trying to make a request with Paypal API, when I make a config file first and then use axios.request everything works fine but when I switch to axios.post(url,body,headers) then I get error 400/bad request,
this call is inside another call, resp is response from last API call
my code with config:

```
  (config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: `${baseApi}/v2/checkout/orders`,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Authorization: `Bearer  ${resp.data.access_token}`,
            },
            data: data,
          });
        axios
          .request(config)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
```

code without using the config variable

```
axios
            .post(
              `${baseApi}/v2/checkout/orders`,
              {data},
              {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  Authorization: `Bearer  ${resp.data.access_token}`,
                },
              },
            )
            .then(response => console.log(response.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
```